# Does Citrix XenServer have a SDK or API?

Tags: virtualization, xenserver

We're presently running Virtual Iron and make extensive use of their SDK and API tools to automate many tasks. Does XenServer 5.5 have an equivalent set of tools other than the command line utilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.

The API spec and sample code is here: http://community.citrix.com/cdn/xs/sdks

The SDK Guide is here: http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/5.5.0/1.0/en_gb/sdk.html

Comment: Nice one...I searched the Citrix site but couldn't find a reference to it. Appreciated.